# why i cannot replace value of a hidden input?

Tags: javascript

i have a hidden input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedItem" value="1,1,1," name="selectedItem"/>
```

and i want to replace some values of it to:

```
value="9,9,9"
```

i tried to used

```
document.getElementById('selectedItem').value = document.getElementById('selectedItem').value.replace(/1/gi,'9')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('selectedItem').value = document.getElementById('selectedItem').value.replace('1','9')
```

but it didnot work. Please someone tells me why and give me some solutions. 
Thank You

Comment: What does the javascript console tell you?

Comment: Your first example should work fine. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/v54rA/

Comment: How and where did you call javascript method???

Comment: your code is working fine, you are doing mistake in some other portion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jquery? Something like the following:

```
$('input#selectedItem').value('9,9,9');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectedItem").val("9,9,9");
//or
$("#selectedItem").val($("#selectedItem").val().replace(/1/gi,'9'));
```

Comment: This will replace the entire value. The OP wants to only replace certain characters.

Comment: @James Allardice, the question asks "why i cannot replace 'value' of a hidden input?"

Comment: In the examples it's clear that the intention is to replace certain characters within the value of the hidden input.

Comment: @James Allardice, Technically speaking, there is no such thing as replace certain *characters of a value* since total value reassignment is necessary DOM wise.  On top of that, i gave both ways of doing it, replacing 'certain characters' as you say and the other way.

Comment: @Babiker - True, you have to assign a new value but you know what I meant. The version you have added is perfect for what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @James Allardice - Sure, no problem :)

Comment: can i replace a certain chracter by a value? i mean like this: var i=1; $("#selectedItem").val($("#selectedItem").val().replace(/+i+/gi,'9'));

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/QRHTL/

It would be a bit cleaner with jQuery though:

```
$('#selectedItem').val($('#selectedItem').val().replace(/1/gi,'9'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another element on your page with `id="selectedItem"`?  If so, `document.getElementById("selectedItem")` might return that instead of the hidden form input you're expecting it to.